# First order logic problem.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is really playing tricks on my mind.

It goes like this...

> There is one whom everybody is for, and that one person is for everybody.

So far I have this...

$$\exists{y}\forall{x} \operatorname{isFor}(x, y) \land \forall{x}\exists{z} \operatorname{isFor}(z, x) \implies y=z$$

However I am not sure if this is correct and I keep changing my answer, can somebody please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

There is an individual who everybody is for. How to interpet the "that one person" in the second part is not clear. But let us assume that there is an implication of uniqueness.

There may still be other individual who are for everybody.

So we will say something like this: (i) there is exactly one person who everybody is for, and that person is for everybody. So in symbols, using $F(s,t)$ for $s$ is for $t$, we have
$$\exists y \Bigl((\forall x F(x,y) \land F(y,x))\land \forall z(\forall w F(w,z)\longrightarrow z=y)\Bigr) .$$

There are other equivalent ways we could say precisely the same thing. For example we might put the uniqueness statement in the middle in order to imitate more closely the order of the English sentence. We could also use fewer variables, the $w$ can be replaced by $x$.

Comment: I could use adrians answer of ∃y∀x[isFor(x,y)∧isFor(y,x)] but it is confusing because its saying "there exists a person that everybody is for him/her and vice versa" but is this explicitly saying there is exactly one person? Or could there be multiple people that fit this situation by saying "there exists x". Ie, there could exist more than one.

Comment: You may be right, it is one of the ambiguities of the English language. I will write a more detailed analysis, that incorporates the interpretation that this person is unique.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following:

$\exists y \, \forall x [\text{isFor}(x,y) \wedge \text{isFor}(y,x)]$

is correct, as the first portion states that there exists a $y$ such that for all $x$, $x$ is for $y$ -- that is, 'There is one whom everybody is for', and the second portion states that, given that $y$, $y$ is for all $x$ -- 'that one person is for everybody'.

Comment: This is the discrepancy that is confusing me. When it says there is one whom everybody is for, and that one person is for everybody, is it saying that there is only one unique person in question, or is it saying that that there happens to be one whom everybody is for, and another person that is for everybody. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Since it says that *that* one person is for everybody, I read it as saying that there is only that one unique person.

Comment: I can parse it two ways.  One is "There is one whom everybody is for, and (that one person) is for everybody."  This is the reading that matches qaphla's response.  The other is "There is one whom everybody is for, and ([it is also true]that) one person is for everybody."  This is the reading André Nicolas is referring to.  It does not imply that the one person that is for everybody is the same one that everybody is for.  I would agree with qaphla's reading, as that is not needed for the other one.  But I agree there is ambiguity.